# Issue with running custom Http Server under MarkLogic 8

Tags: marklogic

Today I've installed MarkLogic 8.05 on my Macbook. For testing a custom website through MarkLogic I created an Http Server. But this new Http Server does not work. When I restart I get the following error(s):

```
2016-04-24 22:18:26.945 Notice: Restarting by user request
2016-04-24 22:18:27.035 Notice: Starting MarkLogic Server 8.0-5.1 x86_64 in /Users/henry/Library/MarkLogic with data in /Users/henry/Library/Application Support/MarkLogic/Data
2016-04-24 22:18:27.040 Info: Host eowyn.local running Darwin 15.4.0
2016-04-24 22:18:27.053 Info: SSL FIPS mode has been enabled
2016-04-24 22:18:27.055 Critical: Server::updateConfigServers: SVC-SOCBIND: Socket bind error: bind 127.0.0.1:80: Permission denied
```

I have tried to start MarkLogic as sudo but this doesn't work either.

Hopefully someone who can help me or point me in the right direction?

I'm running Mac OS X El Capitan with the latest updates.

Thanks,

Henry

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it's an issue with the socket binding to the port. Have you tried another port. Try one that isn't already in use. I find 9100 to be a pretty safe port to us.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that 'low ports'(below 1024) are still only allowed to be bound to by processes started by root.  Therefore, it could be the user for which you are trying to use to start MarkLogic

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to bind to port 80, which is a popular one for HTTP app servers. Perhaps you already have Apache HTTP server or something like that running. Try this:

1. Shut down MarkLogic
2. Use netstat (assuming Linux/Mac) to see whether anything is still listening on port 80.

Netstat:

```
netstat -an | grep 80
```

When I do this for port 8001 with MarkLogic running, I get:

```
tcp4       0      0  *.8001                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

Most likely, you'll see that something is already listening on port 80. Identify that, shut it down, and MarkLogic should be able to take over that port.

Answer (score 2):

To determine if the error is a competing process or no authority run ML as root 
( I tested by running nginx which listens on 80)

If you get this error:

2016-04-25 10:28:40.534 Critical: Server::updateConfigServers: SVC-SOCBIND: Socket bind error: bind 0.0.0.0:80: Address already in use

Then its a competing process on port 80

Run as non-root

2016-04-25 10:31:18.410 Critical: Server::updateConfigServers: SVC-SOCBIND: Socket bind error: bind 0.0.0.0:80: Permission denied

In this case the permission error occurs before the address in use error.

If the problem is a competing process and you need *localhost* access (127.0.0.1) then you need to disable the competing process (2 processes cant listen on the same  port) or configure them such that one listens on 127.0.0.1 and the other on your public interface or on an additional internal interface.

If you need *external* access only then you can arrange manage this with various (somewhat complex) methods such as using a port forwarding router, the Mac equivalent to iptables

https://serverfault.com/questions/102416/iptables-equivalent-for-mac-os-x
An HTTP proxy (squid, ngnix . ... )

-David